# PHP - Curl - multipart/form-data with application/octet-stream for a blank file

Tags: php, file, curl, upload, multipartform-data

I need to be able to send a multipart/form-data post request to the server via PHP and CURL.

I am able to get the correct content type as well as send usual variables, such as below.

```
------------------------------2f860b21c344
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="contactId"

8
------------------------------2f860b21c344
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="wt"

00:00:00
------------------------------2f860b21c344
```

The issue occurs in this section:

```
-----------------------------221901842288
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attchmnt[0]"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------221901842288
```

The closest I have gotten is this:

```
------------------------------2f860b21c344
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attchmnt[0]"

filename="";type=application/octet-stream
------------------------------2f860b21c344
```

I'm using an array for the POST data as the multipart header is required, so as far as the CURL code its working 100% it's just this array that isn't working.
Following is the full DataArray:

```
<?PHP
$dataArray = array(
'tid' => '',
'parentId' => '',
'contactId' => '8',
'wt' => '00:00:00',
'ts' => 'OFF',
'smtl' => '',
'ctctCombo' => 'John Hawkins',
'contact' => '8',
'location' => '16',
'priority' => '-2',
'group' => '1',
'status' => '2',
'category' => '5',
'categoryOption' => '8',
'estimatedDate' => '',
'assignedTo' => '16',
'asset' => '',
'zenAsset' => '',
'cf_20_new' => '512',
'subject' => 'Subject',
'cc' => '',
'bc' => '',
'note' => 'Message',
'attchmnt[0]' => 'filename="";type=application/octet-stream',
'notifyTech' => 'on',
'_notifyTech' => '',
'_notifyUser' => ''
);
?>
```

So the question is, How do I get CURL to add 'filename="";type=application/octet-stream' on the same line as the name="attchmnt[0]"; ?

It would be simple if I could just upload a file, however I need to specify that it is a filestream just no file was uploaded.

Answer (score 3):

There's no **clean** way of doing this, I'm afraid. You could use the @ syntax to upload an existing file (and then cURL specifies the `octet-stream` and also uses the file name you supplied in `filename`. But you can't specify an *empty* filename that way.

You can do this... a multiline injection attack against your own code. cURL doesn't seem to mind, but I don't know if it is *by design*, to allow you to do the dirty deed, or if it is *by accident* and might stop working in the next release:

```
$dataArray['attchmnt[0]"; filename=""'."\r\n".'Content-Type: octet-stream'] = '';
```

This translates to:

```
    0x0a30:  2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d  ----------------
    0x0a40:  2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d33 6331 3837  -----------3c187
    0x0a50:  3162 6630 3132 360d 0a43 6f6e 7465 6e74  1bf0126..Content
    0x0a60:  2d44 6973 706f 7369 7469 6f6e 3a20 666f  -Disposition:.fo
    0x0a70:  726d 2d64 6174 613b 206e 616d 653d 2261  rm-data;.name="a
    0x0a80:  7474 6368 6d6e 745b 305d 223b 2066 696c  ttchmnt[0]";.fil
    0x0a90:  656e 616d 653d 2222 0d0a 436f 6e74 656e  ename=""..Conten
    0x0aa0:  742d 5479 7065 3a20 6f63 7465 742d 7374  t-Type:.octet-st
    0x0ab0:  7265 616d 220d 0a0d 0a0d 0a2d 2d2d 2d2d  ream"......-----
    0x0ac0:  2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d  ----------------
    0x0ad0:  2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d33 6331 3837 3162  ---------3c1871b
    0x0ae0:  6630 3132 362d 2d0d 0a                   f0126--..
```

which should be what you're after.

### Test

```
// $dataArray as defined by you

// Change the 'attchmnt[0]' entry
$dataArray['attchmnt[0]"; filename=""'."\r\n".'Content-Type: octet-stream'] = '';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,         False);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,        False);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            'http://127.0.0.1/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           True);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $dataArray);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: I added that after the line declaring the $dataArray and it just appeneded to the array. I also tried replacing
'attchmnt[0]' => 'filename="";type=application/octet-stream',
with 'attchmnt[0]"; filename=""'."\r\n".'Content-Type: octet-stream' >= '', and that didn't do anything to the array at all. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: Attached test code. But I don't understand how *changing an entry* could have done "nothing to the array at all"... you do nothing else to that array before sending it to cURL, right?

Comment: Nice idea, this helped me with TwitterAPI's statuses/update_with_media. i wasn't able to upload contents of an image from memory until i used this trick. Thanks.

Comment: How do you get rid of the extra double quotes it's adding after the end of `octet-stream"`

Comment: This kludge keeps getting *dirtier* and *dirtier*. Have you tried appending another \r\n immediately after `octet-stream`? It looks like we should give up with cURL and use *straight socket I/O*.

Comment: For years I had been struggling with forms that required at least an empty application/octet-stream to be submitted. Eventually I would send an empty gif file. And here was this simple solution all along. Thanks a lot.